# Reuse react's PropTypes in tests and other parts of code?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Is there an easy/straightforward way to re-use the validation built in to React.PropTypes progrmatically in tests and other code?

For example, if I have:

```
ButtonX.propTypes = {
  className: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

If I load that button with a numerical classname, react will warn in the console.

I would like to re-use all that logic in code, and do something like:

```
validateButtonUsingReactPropTypes({ className: 'my-class' })
```

Is there a known clean way of getting acces to those internals?

Comment: Just a reminder that `propTypes` aren't used in production, so don't rely on them when testing for production.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Test Utilities](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html) article in the docs... It think it would provide some examples of how you can access the validators for testing.

Example using [**renderIntoDocument**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#renderintodocument), based on code from [`ReactJSXElementValidator-test.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9a42f8a0c51320384bae5e105e16aa4954990b81/src/isomorphic/modern/element/__tests__/ReactJSXElementValidator-test.js#L258) in the React GitHub repository.

```
// arrange
RequiredPropComponent = class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <span>{this.props.prop}</span>;
  }
};
RequiredPropComponent.displayName = 'RequiredPropComponent';
RequiredPropComponent.propTypes = {prop: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired};

// act
ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<RequiredPropComponent prop={null} />);

// assert
let testPassed = console.error.calls.count() == 0
```

You can obviously incorporate this into some good testing tools, but this is just the raw call.